# Using eksctl from Go

Tags: go, amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm trying to create an AWS EKS cluster from Go.

The [official SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/eks/) seems less fleshed out than the [GCP equivalent](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/container/v1). For example, I can't find a Go API for easily adding (non-managed) node groups to EKS clusters (I want to use auto-scaling spot fleets as EKS workers, which isn't supported by managed node groups).

Most EKS docs recommend using [eksctl](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl) to create and manage clusters. While it's written in Go, eksctl doesn't have a very clean or documented [Go API](https://godoc.org/github.com/weaveworks/eksctl).

Are there examples of using eksctl programmatically from Go? Or are there other Go wrappers around eksctl? Or perhaps there are other libraries I haven't discovered that make it easy to spin up EKS clusters?

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but you might be interested in [Kubergrunt](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/kubergrunt) which interfaces with EKS from Go.

Comment: I'm heavily using it in https://github.com/mhausenblas/eksphemeral/

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHausenblas, very helpful! It looks like you're shelling out to an eksctl subprocess, or am I misreading your code?

Comment: Yup, that's right. Might want to create an issue on the `eksctl` repo and we take it from there.

Comment: There is an issue already, upvoted: https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/813